# Execute $.ajax when HTML form submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to call `$.ajax` when my HTML form is submitted. I am successfully using `.submit()` to determine when the form is submitted. But the `$.ajax`, when placed within the `.submit()` function, is not executing.

However, when not within the `.submit()` function, the `$.ajax` executes perfectly.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" id="search">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
baseURL = 'http://...';

$("#searchForm").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseURL,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml){ 

            // Code here

        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply need to prevent the default browser submit process.

A submit handler does not override the default process, it simply intercepts it and allows you to do whatever you need before it actually submits ... or in this case gets prevented

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

     // ajax here
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!